# SonarQube Add Rules to Profile from database

Tags: sonarqube

I've created a new profile from database by adding in rules_profiles table.

It is reflecting on the SonarQube UI

However, when I am adding rules to that profile by inserting records in active_rules table and restarting sonar.It is showing those number of records on the SonarQube UI
but clicking that does not show me proper data.

Do I need to add information to any other tables.

Pls help

I am using Sonarqube 4.4

Answer (score 1):

You will **not get any support** on this.

Modifying the database is not the right way to add information to SonarQube or customize it. The DB is not an API, it's just an internal storage system for SonarQube.

So either you do it through the Web interface, or through the [Web Service API](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API). But not directly on the DB.

Comment: Thnx but in the webservice api how and where do we execute the curl -x command .Do i need to write some code